prove $x'X^{ +}=0$ where $X^{+}$ is the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse and $x'X=0$.
$X$ is an $n*n$ symmetric matrix and it is given that $x'X=0$ where $x$ is an $n*1$ vector. Let $X^{+}$ be the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse of $X$.
How to prove $x'X^{
+}=0$??
I am struggling with this problem. Can anyone help?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is $x’$? An $n \times n$ matrix?

$x$ is an $n*1$ vector. I added that condition to the question!

keep in mind $X$ is symmetric and its SVD is easier

Hint: $X^+=\lim_{t\to0}X^T(XX^T+tI)^{-1}$ is equal to $\lim_{t\to0}X(X^2+tI)^{-1}$ when $X$ is real symmetric.
